# How do I adjust the double click speed of my wireless mouse on Android or Samsung DeX?

Tags: samsung, mouse

The default double click speed of mouse seems so fast that I have to try many times before it works.  It is a big trouble for me. I could not find a way to adjust it in Settings.  I am using Samsung Galaxy S21 5G Android phone with DeX connection to a TV.  Thanks.